# Using enum and custom string convertible to set textfield and going back

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, enums, swift4

I have an enum that looks like this:

```
enum Enum1: String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case none = "None"
    case weekly = "Weekly"
    case monthly = "Monthly"
    case quarterly = "Quarterly"
    case semiannually = "Semi-Annually"
    case annually = "Annually"

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            return "None"
        case .weekly:
            return "Weekly"
        case .monthly:
            return "Monthly"
        case .quarterly:
            return "Quarterly"
        case .semiannually:
            return "Semi-Annually"
        case .annually:
            return "Annually"
        }
    }

    var timePeriod: DateComponents {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            return DateComponents(day: 0)
        case .weekly:
            return DateComponents(day: 7)
        case .monthly:
            return DateComponents(month: 1)
        case .quarterly:
            return DateComponents(month: 3)
        case .semiannually:
            return DateComponents(month: 6)
        case .annually:
            return DateComponents(year: 1)
        }
    }

    var targetFrequency: Double {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            return 0.0
        case .weekly:
            return 52.0
        case .monthly:
            return 12.0
        case .quarterly:
            return 4.0
        case .semiannually:
            return 2.0
        case .annually:
            return 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

I have a `pickerView` that has the options none, weekly, monthly, quarterly, ..., annually. When I select this, I want to set a variable, `enumCase`, to the corresponding case using `rawValue`. Eventually I want to push this value into a struct as enumCase.targetFrequency.

How would I go about retrieving the struct and converting the targetFrequency value back to the corresponding case / string description.

I.e. I want to convert the value 52.0 in a struct back to the string "weekly", and was hoping I could use Enum1 and not have to create a second enum, Enum2.

Do I need to create another enum like so to convert the targetFrequency back to the corresponding case?

```
enum Enum2: Double {
    case .none:
        return 0.0
    case .weekly:
        return 52.0
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Use a `[Double: Enum1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could simply create an initialiser that takes a Double as a parameter:

```
// An Int seems a lot safer though
init?(frequency: Double) {
    switch frequency {
    case 0.0:
        self = .none
    case 52.0:
        self = .weekly
    case 12.0:
        self = .monthly
    case 4.0:
        self = .quarterly
    case 2.0:
        self = .semiannually
    case 1.0:
        self = .annually
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Side note: Not sure (from your code) why you want to have the enum string-based though, but if you do you could simplify your `description` function quite a bit:

```
var description: String {
    return rawValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that `targetFrequency` should be an `Int`.

You should use a `[Int: Enum1]` to store the mappings between `targetFrequency` and `Enum1`:

```
static let targetFrequencyDict: [Int: Enum1] = {
    func accumulate(dict: inout [Int: Enum1], freq: Enum1) {
        dict[freq.targetFrequency] = freq
    }
    return [Enum1.none, .weekly, .monthly, .quarterly, .semiannually, .annually].reduce(into: [Int: Frequency](), accumulate)
    }()
```

Then you can use `targetFrequencyDict` to get the `Enum1` value you want:

```
Enum1.targetFrequencyDict[52] // weekly
```

In addition, to reduce some of the switch statements, you can turn `Enum1` into a struct and have `static let`s as the enum cases:

```
struct Frequency: CustomStringConvertible {
    let description: String
    let timePeriod: DateComponents
    let targetFrequency: Int

    private init(description: String, timePeriod: DateComponents, targetFrequency: Int) {
        self.description = description
        self.timePeriod = timePeriod
        self.targetFrequency = targetFrequency
    }

    static let none = Frequency(description: "None", timePeriod: DateComponents(days: 0) , targetFrequency: 0)
    static let weekly = Frequency(description: "Weekly", timePeriod: DateComponents(days: 7) , targetFrequency: 52)
    static let monthly = Frequency(description: "Monthly", timePeriod: DateComponents(months: 1) , targetFrequency: 12)
    static let quarterly = Frequency(description: "Quarterly", timePeriod: DateComponents(months: 3) , targetFrequency: 4)
    static let semiannually = Frequency(description: "Semi-annually", timePeriod: DateComponents(months: 6) , targetFrequency: 2)
    static let annually = Frequency(description: "Annually", timePeriod: DateComponents(years: 1) , targetFrequency: 1)

    static let targetFrequencyDict: [Int: Frequency] = {
        func nextResult(dict: inout [Int: Frequency], freq: Frequency) {
            dict[freq.targetFrequency] = freq
        }
        return [Frequency.none, .weekly, .monthly, .quarterly, .semiannually, .annually].reduce(into: [Int: Frequency](), nextResult)
        }()
}
```